# How make access deny my web page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I want to make access deny one of my web page. and I don't want others can watch this page. while this page i'm using with Iframe in my other web page. I don't know how can I make it access deny this page till in my Iframe page to be avaiable but on that direct web page to be unavailable.

in this page i want to be available ( There is Iframe of b-c-e.us/Stream1 ) : http://tv.b-c-e.us/Bein_Sports_Line1_HD.php

in this page i don't want to be avaiable : b-c-e.us/Stream1

Comment: this is more a security related question

Answer (score 1):

You can create `.htaccess` file in folder where you store this file and write some rules like:

```
<files Bein_Sports_Line1_HD.php>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
```

You can also allow connection from given IP (yours for example), to do it add a line:

```
allow from <your ip>
```

For example:

```
<files Bein_Sports_Line1_HD.php>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 111.222.333.444
</files>
```

More about `.htaccess` you can read [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

---

**Update**

If you dont want anyone to render this page anywhere else you can try to add in your header `X-Frame-Options` as `DENY`. You can add it to `Bein_Sports_Line1_HD.php` and in PHP it would look like follows:

```
header('X-Frame-Options: DENY');
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129359/discussion-on-answer-by-karol-gasienica-how-make-access-deny-my-web-page).